# How many iphone devices can be connected to a Bluetooth device simultaneously?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I found a lot of answers to similar questions as this but all the answer are different. I want to know how many iPhone devices can be connected to a Bluetooth device simultaneously? And in which versions are available this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may depend on the type of device. I believe you can connect as many as you have in your collection, but using each and every one of those devices will depend on the type.

For instance, we are working with BLE devices and I have connected up to 10 to our app and they all work simultaneously, where as I've read you can only connect 2 legacy BT devices such as keyboards or head sets and are only able to use 1 at a time.

I'm pretty sure though that you can pair with as many devices as you can (though I dont have a specific number like max of 20).

### EDIT

**If the iPhone is Master, then you can only connect 1 iPhone to a Slave BT peripheral.**

### UPDATE

I just read from the Apple Bluetooth mailing list that either 7 - 8 devices are supported and even at that number you will have limitations such as bandwidth. So that's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Though is not very clear, I think OP wants to know how many phones you can pair and connect to a single external device, not the other way around

Comment: Ah, yes, must have read that wrong, updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: As I can read in the mailing list archive http://lists.apple.com/archives/bluetooth-dev/2013/Feb/msg00085.html the 7 / 8 limit was for Classic Bluetooth and not for Bluetooth Low Energy